# Issues loading controller angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to inject my controllers in AngularJS using the `ui.router` resolve, but i'm having issues where the template is loading first. My `app.js` is defined below:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('view1', {
            url: "/view1/",
            templateUrl: "view1/view1.html",
            resolve: {'': appendStaticFileToPage("view1/view1.js")}
        })

        .state('view2', {
            url: "/view2/",
            templateUrl: "view2/view2.html",
            resolve: {'': appendStaticFileToPage("view2/view2.js")}
        })

    ;

    function appendStaticFileToPage(file) {
        return function($q){
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.setAttribute('src', file);
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        };
    }

});
```

When the user clicks on a particular link for a state, I inject the `js` file for it into the browser. That part works fine. But the `templateUrl` defines the template to be used and that always loads first. Since it defines an `ng-controller` what happens is that the controller is being loaded, but since its not in the page yet, I get an error in the console that the controller couldn't be found. How can I achieve this?

I have created a simplified version of my code here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/X9uFOMIJq5tCn7VezSzT?p=preview

Is there a way to achieve what I am doing here?

**EDIT**

I previously had promises on my append code, which I'm showing below:

```
function appendStaticFileToPage(file) {
    return function($q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('src', file);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script).ready(function(){
            deferred.resolve();
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
}
```

When I do this, nothing happens. It doesn't load the template. It also doesn't show the `console.log` statements I put in the controllers.

Comment: you forgot to return a promise that gets resolved when the controller has been loaded to your resolve function.

Comment: I tired to do that also. But then the template doesn't get loaded. Seems like nothing happens. I even put console statements in my controllers and they don't appear.

Comment: my guess would be either the script failed to load, or the way you're listening for it to load is incorrect.

Comment: Your edit is close, but, you're still not resolving the deferred, you just created it and then never used it.

Comment: First fix the plunker with correct files included in header, it must be some CDN path then we can try

Comment: Plunkr has been fixed

Comment: The script is properly loading, and it's not being resolved until after the script is loaded, so the problem lies with how (or when) we're attaching the controller to the module. Delaying it longer has no effect which rules out any race conditions.

Comment: I can't explain why there's a need to do this, but, injecting $controllerProvider and using it to register the controller seems to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/D5BsLhcWt200welLLTFU?p=preview If someone can explain why that works, it would make for a good answer.

Comment: I updated my plunkr with your suggestions, not completely the same but similar. And it works like a charm :). Will accept your answer if you put it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since registering it with .controller isn't working, and I can confirm that the script is loading properly and executing, I tried instead injecting the `$controllerProvider` service and registering the controller through there, and it works.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $controllerProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('view1', {
            url: "/view1/",
            templateUrl: "view1.html",
            resolve: {'': appendStaticFileToPage("view1.js", "MyViewOneController")}
        })

        .state('view2', {
            url: "/view2/",
            templateUrl: "view2.html",
            resolve: {'': appendStaticFileToPage("view2.js", "MyViewTwoController")}
        })

    ;

    function appendStaticFileToPage(file, controllerName) {
        return function($q){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.onload = function () {
                $controllerProvider.register(controllerName, window[controllerName])
                deferred.resolve();
            };
            script.onerror = function () {
                deferred.reject();
            };
            script.setAttribute('src', file);
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

            return deferred.promise;
        };
    }

});
```

I had to also update view1.js and view2.js as follows:

```
'use strict';
window.MyViewOneController = function($scope) {
  console.log("Got to view 1");
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to not do the `script.onload` an `script.onerror` here? I want to abstract the the script and `document.getElementByTagName` into a different method.

Comment: Yes, you could instead have your script(viewn.js) call a method or trigger an event